# SQL join with 2 tables - sort distinct result on column of second join

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-order-by

Sorry for the bad title, but I don't know how to describe it better.

I have 3 tables

1.) contests

```
ID   Title
----------
1    Contest 1
2    Contest 2
3    Contest 3
```

2.) contest_series

```
ID   contest_id   series_id
----------------------------
1    1            3
2    1            2
3    2            1
4    2            2
5    3            3
```

3.) series

```
ID   start_date
----------------
1    2018-03-21 14:00:00
2    2018-03-21 15:00:00
3    2018-03-21 16:00:00
```

Now what I try to achieve is, getting a list of contests ordered by the start_date of the first starting series in the contest.

Wanted Result:

```
contest_id   start_date_of_first_series
------------------------
2            2018-03-21 14:00:00
1            2018-03-21 15:00:00
3            2018-03-21 16:00:00
```

Important: the contest_id in the result needs to be distinct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is just a `join` and `group by`:

```
select cs.contest_id, min(s.start_date) as first_start_date
from contest_series cs join
     series s
     on cs.series_id = s.series_id
group by cs.contest_id
order by first_start_date;
```

Comment: first thanks for editing my post for a correct layout. Second, thanks for this. I think I thought a little bit too complicated on this...

Answer (score 0):

I slightly modified it, but @Gordon Linoff guided me in the right direction and solved my problem:

```
select contests.* from contests
join (
    select contest_series.contest_id, min(series.start) as first_start_date
    from contest_series
    join series on contest_series.series_id = series.id
    group by contest_series.contest_id
    ) filtered_contests on filtered_contests.contest_id = contests.id
order by first_start_date
```